# Applying multiple group functions on IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

Given the following simple object

```or-tag-here
public class Foo {
    public int PrimaryKey;
    public int ForeignKey;
    public bool FlagOne;
    public bool FlagTwo;
}
```

Suppose I have received a `IQueryable<Foo>`. Generally, if I want to do a count operation on each flag I would do this:

```or-tag-here
IQueryable<Foo> foos = GetFoos();
var total = foos.Count();
var flagOneTotal = foos.Count(p => p.FlagOne);
var flagTwoTotal = foos.Count(p => p.FlagTwo);
```

In EF, the above would execute 3 queries in the database. I would like to retrieve all these in a single query.

For grouping, I can do this to execute single query:

```or-tag-here
var q = from foo in foos
        group foo by foo.ForeignKey into g
        select new {
           ForeignKey = g.Key,
           Total = g.Count(),
           FlagOneTotal = g.Count(p => p.FlagOne),
           FlagTwoTotal = g.Count(p => p.FlagTwo)
        };

var list = q.ToList();
```

But how would I do the same if I want to get the totals for all elements regardless of foreign key in a single query and a single anonymous object ?

In other words, how would I tell .net that all elements in `foos` need to be considered 1 group so I can do Count operations on them.

Comment: Is your ultimate goal only to avoid 3 hits to the database ?

Comment: @LucMorin This is just a sample but that's not the point. I would like to learn if there is a way to do that or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
var q = from foo in foos
        group foo by 1 into g
        select new {
           Total = g.Count(),
           FlagOneTotal = g.Count(p => p.FlagOne),
           FlagTwoTotal = g.Count(p => p.FlagTwo)
        };

var list = q.ToList();
```

Cheers

Comment: `g.Key` would hold the value 1 not the value of `ForeignKey`

Comment: @AlaaMasoud I just removed it from the query, as he said "regardless of the foreign key", which I take it that doesn't need it.